# TFS Query to return weekly closure of User Stories

Tags: tfs, dashboard

I am trying to create a Query in TFS Cloud which would help us create a bar graph in the dashboard showing how Many Story Points have been Closed per week in last 2 months. So the bar graph should approximately have 8 bars (8 weeks in 2 months) each representing a week and showing the Sum of Story points of Closed User Stories during that week. Is it possible to write such a query using TFS Query feature? If so, can someone please help. Would highly appreciate any guidance on this.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't achieve your requirement that create one query to return weekly closure. You need to create 8 query by selecting create/change date and customize your own chart.

You could develop your own extension by starting from the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/overview?view=vsts

Comment: OK. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use condition

ClosedDate > @StartOfWeek

or

ClosedDate > @StartOfWeek - 7

or

ClosedDate > @StartOfWeek - 14